# EJB's with normal method interfaces (not local and remote)

Tags: ejb, jndi, code-injection, classcastexception

I'm building multiple DAO's that consists of two other DAO's. I have made a generic class to handle invocations on the sub-dao's, since this is always the same.

My problem is that for this to work, i had to put an interface containing only methods (not marked local or remote!) on the sub-dao's. All dao's are stateless beans.

When i try to @EJB the dao's however, i get:

```
com.dao.EJSLocal0SLSomeDao_85a3a0b7 cannot be cast to com.dao.SomeDao
```

Is there any way to tweak this so i can use an interface not related to Local or Remote?

Kind Regards
Tom

Comment: Are you using `@EJB`, or are you using lookup+cast? I'm not sure why you would get a ClassCastException for an `@EJB`; can you show the full error message with a stack trace? Is com.dao.SomeDao your EJB implementation class? What does your lookup look like? You can only cast to the implementation class if you're using no-interface view from EJB 3.1.

Comment: bkail, i was not using a no-interface view. I added @Localbean to the class and it now works like a charm :-). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to cast the bean implementation class, then you need to use no-interview view (that is, annotate the EJB with `@LocalBean`).  If you look up an unrelated interface, you can the proxy that is returned can only be cast to that specific interface.